# Need to get values of all non ticked checkboxes in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi am using jquery data table with pagination and the The list is very huge it seems to be around 365 pages(ie: jquery pagination each page with 10 results).
The user may elect the checbox from any page  so currently am getting the values of all checkboxes he ticked across all pages with pagination.Am getting the ticked values through

```
 var oTable = $('#assignUser').dataTable();
var rowcollectionChecked =  oTable.$(".rowCheckerClass:checked", {"page": "all"});
```

This seems to be working fine.

**Now I need to get all unticked checboxes values excluding the selected one in an array.**
Could someone help me out with this.

AM not able to create a fiddle 
here is the onClick event getting called

```
Liferay.provide(
                window,
                '<portlet:namespace/>submitFormForAction',
                function() {
                    var accepted = confirm('<%= UnicodeLanguageUtil.get(pageContext, 
                            "are-you-sure-you-want-to-update-associations") %>');
                    var oTable = $('#assignUser').dataTable();
                    var rowcollectionChecked =  oTable.$(".rowCheckerClass:checked", {"page": "all"});
                    var rowcollectionNotChecked =oTable.$(".rowCheckerClass:not(checked)", {"page": "all"});
                    var checkedIds = [];
                    var notCheckedIds = [];

                    rowcollectionChecked.each(function(index,elem){
                        var checkbox_value = $(elem).val();
                        checkedIds.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    rowcollectionNotChecked.each(function(index,elem){
                        var checkbox_value = $(elem).val();
                        notCheckedIds.push($(this).val());
                    });


                    if (accepted) {
                        var frm = document.<portlet:namespace/>fm;
                        var hiddenField1 = frm.<portlet:namespace/>addUserIds;
                        var hiddenField2 = frm.<portlet:namespace/>removeUserIds;
                        hiddenField1.value = checkedIds;
                        hiddenField2.value = notCheckedIds
                        submitForm(frm);
                    }
                },
            ['liferay-util-list-fields']
        );
```

The values for checked seems to be fine but for unchecked values it is returning count of entire data
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as this:

Add `not` before `checked`

```
var rowcollectionChecked =  oTable.$(".rowCheckerClass:not(checked)", {"page": "all"});
```

Comment: Hi adding not is still giving me checked ones also

Comment: can you create a fiddle??

Comment: @ravicandy.. Just console log the `rowcollectionNotChecked ` and let me know what you are getting??

Comment: Hi Guru thanks it worked :) the above query it was not working because of some conflicts thanks

Comment: great!! Anyways! Happy  coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

```
var rowcollectionChecked =  oTable.$(".rowCheckerClass:not(:checked)", {"page": "all"});
```

Comment: Hi adding not is still giving me checked ones also

Comment: make sure using :checked not check